# LDAP - Subversion Issue

Tags: svn, ldap, tuleap

We recently integrated LDAP with Tuleap, we were using Tuleap for past 1 year, but recently we integrated LDAP.  We face an issue especially in one project as below. We are unable to access the Browse SVN tree option - When I go to subversion--> Browse SVN tree (in Tuleap.) The below error occurs:

```
An exception has occurred.
** Python Traceback.**
**Traceback (most recent call last):**

File "/usr/share/viewvc/lib/viewvc.py", line 3814, in main
     request.run_viewvc()
File "/usr/share/viewvc/lib/viewvc.py", line 318, in run_viewvc
        if not svnaccess.check_read_access(user.user_getname(), self.rootpath, self.where):
File "/usr/share/tuleap/src/www/../utils/svn/svnaccess.py", line 130, in check_read_access
        username = get_name_for_svn_access(svnrepo, username)
File "/usr/share/tuleap/src/www/../utils/svn/svnaccess.py", line 119, in get_name_for_svn_access
        return codendildap.get_login_from_username(username)
File "/usr/share/tuleap/src/www/../utils/svn/codendildap.py", line 60, in get_login_from_username
        return get_login_from_eduid(row['ldap_id'])
File "/usr/share/tuleap/src/www/../utils/svn/codendildap.py", line 43, in get_login_from_eduid
        l = ldap_connect()
File "/usr/share/tuleap/src/www/../utils/svn/codendildap.py", line 33, in ldap_connect
        l = ldap.open(server)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/ldap/functions.py", line 104, in open
        return initialize('ldap://%s:%d' % (host,port),trace_level,trace_file,trace_stack_limit)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/ldap/functions.py", line 85, in initialize
        return LDAPObject(uri,trace_level,trace_file,trace_stack_limit)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 69, in __init__
        self._l = ldap.functions._ldap_function_call(_ldap.initialize,uri)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/ldap/functions.py", line 57, in _ldap_function_call
        result = func(*args,**kwargs)
    LDAPError: (0, 'Error')
```

Below is the LDAP config for your reference.

```
$sys_ldap_server = 'X.X.X.X:xxx'; 
$sys_ldap_cn='cn';
$sys_ldap_people_dn='ou=Users,dc=xxxx,dc=org'; 
$sys_ldap_search_user='(|(uid=%words%)(cn=%words%))'; 
$sys_ldap_default_user_status='A'; 
$sys_ldap_svn_auth=1; 
$sys_ldap_daily_sync=1; 
$sys_ldap_user_management=1; 
$sys_ldap_grp_enabled = 1; 
$sys_ldap_grp_dn='ou=groups,dc=xxxx,dc=org'; 
$sys_ldap_grp_cn = 'cn'; 
$sys_ldap_grp_member='uniquemember';
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you replace

```
$sys_ldap_server = 'X.X.X.X:xxx'
```

By

```
$sys_ldap_server = 'ldap(s)://X.X.X.X:xxx'
```

the (s) depending if you are using ssl or not